# How to highlight searched text in angular6, using pipe?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-pipe

I want to build a search box in angular, that would return the array of item,and also highlight the searcchedTerm in the results array.

For example: In Chrome if you are searching any text, it would highlight with light yellow background. Similar to that.

[image]

I have created two pipes, one to filter the result and another to highlight the term **in the results** which is searched.
But i am getting error `replace is not a function`.

And also, can the two pipes be merged into one?

**highlight.pipe.ts**

```
transform(list: any, searchText: string): any[] {
    if (!list) { return []; }
    if (!searchText) { return list; }

    const re = new RegExp(searchText, 'gi');
    const value = list.replace(re, "<span class='yellow'>" + searchText + "</span>" );
    return list;
}
```

**using the pipe in template**

`<div class="card" *ngFor="let item of list | search: searchedTerm | highlight: searchedTerm">`

Comment: Can you add the code where you're trying to do `replace` please? Or just add all of the code from your pipes

Comment: i have already given the stackblitz url, where you can find the full code. And also added the code here.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. You may be better off using a `directive` rather than a `pipe`. Here is an example you can check in GitHub https://github.com/arthurvaverko/ngx-highlight

Answer (score 4):

**I**
Iterate over filtered `list` by `searchedTerm`.
Place highlighted html into `innerHTML`.

```
// html
<div class="card" *ngFor="let item of list | search: searchedTerm">
  <span [innerHTML]="item.name | highlight: searchedTerm"></span>
</div>
```

**II**

```
// HighlightPipe
const re = new RegExp(searchText, 'gi');
return item.replace(re, `<span class='yellow'>${searchText}</span>` );
```

**III**

Use deprecated (move to global styles) `deep` as components by default have Emulated [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation)

```
// css
::ng-deep .yellow{
  background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I had the highlight pipe to the array instead of the name. I got it now. thanks

Answer (score 3):

1- In the highlight.pipe.ts

```
transform(list: any, searchText: string): any[] {
console.log('lists', list);
console.log('searchText', searchText);

if (!list) { return []; }
//to remove highlighted tags before any processing
list = list.map(function (item) {
  item.name = item.name ? String(item.name).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '') : '';
  return item;
})
if (!searchText) { return list; }

const re = new RegExp(searchText, 'gi');
const value = list
  .map(function (item) {
    //this will match the values and add the highlight tag for it
    item.name = item.name.replace(re, "<span class='yellow'>" + searchText + "</span>");
    return item
  });
return value;
```

}

2- Move the .yellow style to style.css to match for the injected html

3- In the app.component.html

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let item of list | search: searchedTerm | highlight: searchedTerm">
 <span [innerHTML]="item.name"></span>
</div>
```

If you want the items to disappear then use the search pipe if you only want it highlighted then the highlight pipe alone is enough

a link for the updated Stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-searchpipe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: thanks for the reply. The changes you have done are not saved. You need to Fork(top left button, in blue color) my exampe and then do the changes. only then your changes would be saved.